# unable to update systemd from 232-25+deb9u2 to 232-25+deb9u4 on raspbian device

Tags: apt, systemd, raspbian

My real goal is to run systemd-journal-remote so I can send logs from this device to the remote journal sink. *apt-get update/upgrade* show no packages needing upgrades

```
$ sudo apt-get install systemd-journal-remote
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 systemd-journal-remote : Depends: systemd (= 232-25+deb9u4) but 232-25+deb9u2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

$ sudo apt-get install systemd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
systemd is already the newest version (232-25+deb9u2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

$ cat /etc/issue
Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 \n \l

$ cat /etc/debian_version
9.4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the reason.  Check for a file in /etc/apt/preferences.d ending with ".pref".  In my case I had a file named 10-somefilename.pref which was holding all my packages to their initial versions.